# knockoutjs: value binding exclusive or click event?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm going through the knockoutjs tutorial. I've slighly modified it to see what happens. So I started with the "working with lists and collections" tutorial. First, I wanted to replace the  tag by a div (this didn't work 100% either but that's not the subject of this post). Then, I wanted not only to bind the table cells to model values but also have an event handler for - let's say onClick. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<div data-bind="foreach: seats">
     <div style="clear: left; display: table; width: 100%;"  >
          <input data-bind="value: name; click: $parent.onClick;" type="text"/>
     </div>
     <div style="width: 300px; float: left; display: table; width: 100%">
         <select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'; select: $root.onClick"></select>
     </div>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
```

JS:

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Kai", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);

    // Operations
    self.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push (new SeatReservation ("<Please fill>", self.availableMeals[0]));
    }

    self.onClick = function () { alert ('Lets make love'); }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

The problem is that the click event isn't handled correctly. With the above code, the click on the input element won't have any effect. If I swap the order of the event and value attributes (data-bind="click: $parent.onClick; value: name;" instead of the code above) the click event works but the data binding doesn't take place (the input remains empty). I see the same effect, even though less surprising if the data-bind tag only contains the click.
What am I doing wrong? I want to have both click event handler *and* data binding for the input element.
I'm testing with Firefox on Windows 7.

Many thanks
Kai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings in Knockout are separated by a comma, not a semi-colon.  Also, leave off the trailing semi-colon.

```
<input data-bind="value: name, click: $parent.onClick" type="text"/>
```